# Redux: Unable to send action Data to a Store

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I started using redux and read the document for sending action data to the store. I tried doing it but nothing is happening.

What is supposed to happen is when they press **PLAY** on the screen **BookViewScreen.js** a bottom media panel should appear but it's not the case here. Nothing is happening when I try to send action data to the store.

**App.js**

```
...

const store = createStore(combineReducers(media), {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

...

function mapStateToProps1({ media }) {
  return { media };
}
const MediaBottomPanel = connect(mapStateToProps1)(bottomMediaPanel);

...   

export default class App extends React.Component {
   
...

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigation theme="dark" />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**media.js** reducer

```
  import { UPDATE_MEDIA } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  mediaList: null,
  currentlyPlaying: null,
};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_MEDIA:
      return action.media;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**media.js** action

```
import { UPDATE_MEDIA } from './types';



export const updateMedia = (media, callback) => dispatch => {
  
  dispatch({type: UPDATE_MEDIA, media: media});
  if(callback)
    callback();
};
```

**BookViewScreen.js** Where I try to send action data.

```
   ...

    import * as mediasActions from '../store/actions/media';
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

   ...
    
    const BookViewScreen  = (props, navigation) => {
      
...

  
    
                <Button
                  onPress={() => {
                    isAudio(!audio)
                    mediasActions.updateMedia({
                      info: {
                        author,
                        title,
                        cover,
                      },
                      currentlyPlaying: audios[0],
                      mediaList: audios,
                    })
                  }
    >
              ...
```

Here is the full github project if you are interested: [Audiod](https://github.com/ownsupernoob2/audiod/tree/master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here https://github.com/ownsupernoob2/audiod/blob/master/src/screens/BookViewScreen.js#L93 you're calling the action as if it was a normal function. But it doesn't work like that in redux. Try:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
const dispatch = useDispatch(); // in the body of the function component
dispatch(mediasActions.updateMedia(...)) // play button click handler
```

There's two ways to dispatch actions:

1. `useDispatch` hook for function components
2. `mapDispatchToProps` argument for the `connect()` API for function and class components